# Bluez BLE Connection Linux

Tags: c, linux, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, hci

I'm very new to Linux and Bluetooth development, and I'm unsure of the difference between `sudo hcitool lecc <bdaddr>` and `sudo gatttool -b <dbaddr> -I`? I don't require any of the GATT services; I just want a connection between the two devices.

I'm looking at vaguely following [this widely referred to tutorial](http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x502.html#rfcomm-server.c), and am looking at adapting the `cmd_lecc` method in Bluez /tools/hcitool.c, but I am unable to connect to my BLE device using `hcitool lecc`.

When I connect using `gatttool`, I am able to connect successfully, however using `hcitool lecc` returns the error 'Could not create connection: Connection timed out', and no connection is made to the BLE device. However, running `sudo hcitool con` to show active connections shows that there is one: 'Unknown  handle 0 state 2 lm SLAVE'. If it's failing to make the connection, why is it then registering the connection as active in `hcitool`?

My question therefore is threefold:

1. What is the difference between the two commands?
2. Would `gatttool` be suitable for my purpose, or should I work out what's not working with `hcitool` (following something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853597/ble-gatttool-cannot-connect-even-though-device-is-discoverable-with-hcitool-lesc)?
3. Why does `sudo hcitool lecc <bdaddr>` partially connect, even when it times out?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hcitool lecc <bdaddr>` creates a connection and returns a handle, while `gatttool -b <bdaddr> -I` only opens an interactive terminal with an interface bound to the address but not yet connected. To connect using the `gatttool` command you must then enter `connect`, which will most likely also fail.

I would suggest looking at how `hcitool` connects for writing your own code as all of `gatttool` simply is a wrapper around the same process that `hcitool` uses, but its wrapper is not available unless you copy its code.

lastly, the handle 0 that `hcitool` is reporting is an invalid handle left from trying to connect, because as far as I've seen all valid handles are greater than 0.