# Cannot connect to BLE device on Raspberry Pi

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I'm trying to connect to a BLE device (Heart rate sensor, Polar H7), on a Raspberry Pi 2. I use the last version of bluez (5.35) found here: http://www.bluez.org/download/
But when I'm trying to connect using `gatttool`, I always have "connection refused" error.

Here is what I do :

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo su
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# hciconfig dev
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
        BD Address: 5C:F3:70:69:54:3D  ACL MTU: 1021:8 SCO MTU: 64:1
        DOWN
        RX bytes:616 acl:0 sco:0 events:34 errors:0
        TX bytes:380 acl:0 sco:0 commands:34 errors:0

root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# hciconfig dev up
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# hcitool lescan
LE Scan ...
00:22:D0:6D:E0:E6 (unknown)
00:22:D0:6D:E0:E6 Polar H7 6DE0E61C
^Croot@raspberrypi:/home/pi# hcitool lecc 00:22:D0:6D:E0:E6
Connection handle 64
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# gatttool -b 00:22:D0:6D:E0:E6 -I
[00:22:D0:6D:E0:E6][LE]> connect
Attempting to connect to 00:22:D0:6D:E0:E6
Error connect: Connection refused (111)
[00:22:D0:6D:E0:E6][LE]>
```

I tried to follow this topic: [BLE gatttool cannot connect even though device is discoverable with hcitool lescan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853597/ble-gatttool-cannot-connect-even-though-device-is-discoverable-with-hcitool-lesc)
but it did not work for me.

Comment: If you have Bluez, why not just use bluetoothctl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to disable the plugin `pnat` in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` -> `DisablePlugins=pnat`. I read that it's unstable, but I don't know much about this plugin.

Comment: Good grief, this is the most underrated answer ever! This solved every problem I had on a Raspbian system, after days of other attempts.

Answer (score 42):

I was able to connect via `Bluetooth` from `Raspberry` to my `Android` device using `gatttool` after setting the `LE address type` to `random` with the `-t random` argument, i.e. :

```
sudo gatttool -t random -b DD:9D:0B:43:A1:77 -I
connect
```

---

From `gatttool` [man](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man1/gatttool.1.html)

```
--t, ---addr-type=[public | random] 
# Set LE address type. Default: public
```

---

```
USAGE gatttool [OPTION...]

 Help Options:
     -h, --help                                  Show help options
     -h, --help                                  Show help options
     --help-all                                  Show all help options
     --help-gatt                                 Show all GATT commands
     --help-params                               Show  all  Primary  Services/Characteristics
   arguments
     --help-char-read-write                       Show  all  Characteristics Value/Descriptor
   Read/Write arguments

   Application Options:
     --i, ---adapter=hciX                        Specify local adapter interface
     --b, ---device=MAC                          Specify remote Bluetooth address
     --t, ---addr-type=[public | random]         Set LE address type. Default: public
     --m, ---mtu=MTU                             Specify the MTU size
     --p, ---psm=PSM                             Specify the PSM for GATT/ATT over BR/EDR
     --l, ---sec-level=[low | medium | high]     Set security level. Default: low
     --I, ---interactive                         Use interactive mode
```

Comment: What if someone did all of the things in this post? Turning on BLE, using -t random and the connection is still refused? Asking for a friend.

Answer (score 6):

By default GATT is not enable. Add the below lines to /etc/bluetooth/main.conf

```
EnableLE = true           // Enable Low Energy support. Default is false.
AttributeServer = true    // Enable the GATT attribute server. Default is false.
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it running with:

```
btmgmt le on
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are still wondering why the `random` from [@Pedro Lobito's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44213932/327074) worked. I have gone through the code and this what I found.

> ```
> ​-t ​(Addr:Type: Set LE Address Type)
> ```

```
Public | random    
Default: Public
```

> A random or static address is a 48-bit randomly generated address and shall meet the following
> requirements:
>
> • The two most significant bits of the static address shall be equal to ‘1’
>
> • All bits of the random part of the static address shall not be equal to ‘1’
>
> • All bits of the random part of the static address shall not be equal to ‘0’

([Source](https://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless_connectivity/bluetooth_low_energy/f/538/t/247015))

Comment: A link as comment on my answer would be more appropriate than creating a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the connection refused (111) issue in my raspberry pi 3B running raspbian buster by Updating/installing BlueZ via apt-get

`> sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends bluetooth`

and re running

`> sudo gatttool -t random -b E9:1C:89:B7:16:F9 -I`

Answer (score -1):

You could try to use `gatttool -b 00:22:D0:6D:E0:E6 -I` and then connect, just after discovering the MAC without connecting before with `hcitool lecc 00:22:D0:6D:E0:E6`